# Rotated shape's fixed point is moving when resizing

Tags: svg, rotation, resize

I'm building graphic editing web page using svg. 
Almost everything is fine except resizing rotated rect. 
The problem is, the fixed point (the opposite one that moves to resize) is not fixed. 
It's almost fixed, but slightly moving around while resizing. 
I think this problem is common because some of the examples has same result. 
Try below example (6. Putting it all together). 
 
https://shihn.ca/posts/2020/resizing-rotated-elements/ 
 
Why this happen and how can I fix this?

Comment: ps. I don't think this is any mathematical error

Comment: Did you write the content on that page?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the slight jiggle of the fixed corner, then that will just be due to matematical rounding errors.  If you don't want it to jiggle like that, then calculate the position of that fixed corner **once**, after the rotation changes.  Then reuse thos coordinates while you are dragging the other corner.  Don't recalculate the corner every time.

Comment: I've tried it before. But rounding numbers or fixing the fixed point doesn't help. Atually the 'recalulate error' is about 1*10^-10, so I don't think the error is only problem. May mixig div tag and svg tag for drawing shapes would cause this problem. Even famous commercial web office has same problem.

Comment: Then perhaps it's just an artifact of the 2D renderer then. Interesting.

Comment: Using g elements under one svg elemnent can fix this problem. I think mix div and svg tags cause the problem.